# What is the reason for intellij IDEA for not launching (Failed to load JVM DLL)?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-11

[image]

On my computer (64 bit operating system, x64 based processor) I installed Amazon Correto JDK 11 (for 64 bit) and IntelliJ IDEA. it was working till today without any issues. But now I can not open my Intellij IDEA. In fact it is not even launching.

I checked the environment variables and path reference of Java. It is all set. But when I double click on Intellij IDEA it is showing loading sign for a moment but it is not launching. I tried to run the same by going to it's directory and by using cmd. But still it is not launching. When I try to open the 32-bit version I get an error, but I know it is obvious, because I am using a JDK version for 64 bit. I want to know why my Intellij IDEA is not launching. Even after downloading the appropriate Java version and setting up the path correctly. There were no issues till today. I tried reinstalling my Java and Intellij. Still the issue is there. If anyone can help, please let me know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run 32-bit `idea.exe` while your default JDK points to 64-bit JDK, hence the problem. Please use `idea64.exe` instead that will run on the [bundled JetBrains Runtime](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).

In case `idea64.exe` also fails, please run using `idea.bat` inside `cmd.exe` to see if there any errors logged in the console.

Perform the steps from [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559) if the issue is caused by some plug-in or corrupted options.